# Error: Request failed with status code 404 at createError (createError.js:16:1) at settle (settle.js:17:1) at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (xhr.js:66:1)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

[image]

terminal won't help
[image]I can't see errors on my terminal
idk where im going wrong I've solved some ESlint errors and now that im done fixing them it still doesn't work and just gives 404

[image]

Comment: 404 means the resource can't be found - it has nothing to do with ESLint. Look in your browser dev tools at the network tab and see what's happening to your request, and whether you're hitting the right endpoint.

Comment: Welcome, if you'd like help be sure to add code samples in your question (reproducible, if possible) which showcases the issue (mention libraries and frameworks as applicable), explain what you have tried already, and describe your expected outcome.

Comment: im sorry but im new to react and js libraries but im having trouble deploying this repo directory https://github.com/mansisindhu/epic-games

Comment: Look at the error @sam4. `:3000/undefined/games`. `undefined` should tell you what is missing.

Comment: Im trying to figure it out I have been searching the net and testing for hours now can you help me relating w it

Comment: is it something with .env file?